# What are the differences between Anchored, Framed and FramedCloud?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup

From the [API document](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/Anchored-js.html) for OpenLayers, I can tell that a `FramedCloud` has more functionalities than `Framed`, which in turn has more functionalities than `Anchored`. I am hoping for someone to describe these differences in a way which a lay person like me can understand.

Comment: check out OpenLayers Popup Matrix example [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/popupMatrix.html). it can help you to understand their structure.

Comment: Provided link is dead.

Comment: To see the OpenLayers Popup Matrix go to the [Open Layers Example Page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/) and search for "Popup Matrix".

Answer (score 1):

As @randlet and @Aragon mentioned, You might want to have a look at the following example: [Popup Matrix](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/popupMatrix.html)

That only compares Anchored and FramedCloud variants. Visually one can see that the FramedCloud class Popup looks like a speech bubble with a arrow pointing to the anchor. Anchored class Popup is just a rectangle.

Comment: Your link is 404.

Comment: @Aaron: updated link; I know I should copy the information from there to here for permanency, but I do not know a good way to do that, since the information is presented as a Javascript page.